# Integral of a function depending on two variables

Tags: integration, limits, functions

I have a function that depends on two parameters, say $f(x,y)$.

Now I need to integrate this function from $0$ to $y_{max}$. I have all the values of $x$ and $y$ and also the values of this function stored in a list, i.e. **they are values as well**.

Now I need to do:

$w = \int_{0}^{y_{max}}f(x,y)dy $

Is this similar to integrating a constant, i.e. $\int xdx$ given the values of $x$. If so also how to proceed with the limits of $y_{max}$? Is is just literally the function integrated to the maximum value of $y$?

Comment: If you integrate with respect to $y$ then $x$ is *treated* as a constant. e.g. $$\int_a^b xy \ dy = x\cdot \int_a^b y\ dy$$

Comment: @DavidP In my case I have values for the function $f(x,y)$, how do I proceed if this is the case?

Comment: You need to be given an explicit function to calculate the integral. If you only have a finite list of values of the function for particular x,y then an integral doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidP Can I instead just sum over the values within each bin instead of performing the integration?